# Delete a char inside a string obtained with scanf

Tags: c, scanf

I have a program in C that use the scanf function as

```
scanf("%248[0-9a-zA-Z]",message);
```

It works, but I want to implement it so that I can modify the message, erasing the last char if I push the delete button(127 in ASCII), I know that I should first allow the value in scanf as

```
scanf("%248[0-9a-zA-ZDEL]",message);
```

I think, also I do not know how to detect it and erase it.

When I enter the Delete It errase all the message that I had type, but instead of that I only want to errase the last char, is there any function that does that? or should I made a longer script reading each char?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Maybe this is an X-Y problem

Comment: But that is already possible while you are inputting a string, right? It doesn't "take" until you press return.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your question, and maybe actually *ask* something inside your question?

Comment: Also, line-editing might be handled by your terminal program, so it might not send any input like that to your program.

Comment: When I press Delete know it delete all the string I have, @CinCout I need it to be more user-friendly

Comment: What OS or runtime environment are you running this in?

Comment: @melpomene I am using a zynqberry programed with a SDK in vivado

Comment: Do you have both a Delete key and a backspace key? Do they do different things? 30 years ago it used to be the case that Delete sent an interrupt signal to the program in some variants of Unix, but I wonder if that is still the default setting anywhere. If it is, the 'stty' program may help you.